# ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development appsettings.Development.json not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

In my project i have the following files:

**appsettings.json** and **appsettings.Development.json**

so the idea is to load the file **appsettings.Development.json** in the **Development** environement and the **appsettings.json** for the **production** environement.

in the **launchSettings.json** i changed the **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** to Development:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

this works as expected as the :

```
env.IsDevelopment() is true
```

the appsettings is loaded like this:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .Build();
```

but still all the values are loaded from the appsettings.json and not the appsettings.Development.json.

i also tried:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", true, true)
                .Build();
```

but the values are always loaded from the last file in this case appsettings.Development.json even if the :

```
env.IsDevelopment() is false
```

Comment: Check this out for .NET 6: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76909010/8644294

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to compose the name of that environment specific settings file, instead of setting a fixed one.

```
$"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json"
```

For the `Development` environment it will be
`appsettings.Development.json`.
For `Production` it will be `appsettings.Production.json`.

If you don't have such a file, only `appsettings.json` will be used, since you have set `optional: true` in that `AddJsonFile` call.

```
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, true)
```

---

You might want to make `appsettings.json` a required file in order to not end up without any settings.

```
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, true)
```

---

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, true)
    .Build();
```

Comment: yes exactly after few research i found that the person who created the project made a mistake by creating an istance of the `ConfigurationBuilder` everytime he wants to get a specific value from the config file.
so what i did instead is injecting the `IConfiguration` in the controller and passing it to the service class, and the framework manages the `EnvironmentName` by extracting it from `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and i removed all the `AddJsonFile` methods.