# Published Blazor WASM application not using appsetting.Development.json

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, deployment, blazor, blazor-webassembly

The application persists in using 'appsettings.json' instead of 'appsettings.Development.json.'

I used the Debug configuration, and I have already set 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' to 'Development'(in the respective IIS Website), but it appears that only the 'appsettings.json' file is being used.

What could be causing the application to ignore the 'appsettings.Development.json' file, and how can I ensure that the correct configuration is applied during deployment?
Any assistance or advice in fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, Wasm can't read the environment so that was not the right approach.

Comment: I understand, but in that case, how am I able to set up an {environment}.appsettings?

Comment: Similar questions you can use as a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239705/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239705/13336642).